# Python StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in selenium And when I doing the job in for loop it gave an error. The first-time loop works well when its reach for a second time it's given below error.

```
elenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I have tried with Time.wait as well as webdriver.wait

```
def function(foo):
    driver.get("https://truckbhada.com/PostedLoadDetails?st=Maharashtra")
    token = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="k-selectable"]/tbody/tr/td/a')

    for tr in token:
        tr.click()
        tr = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnloaddetails")
        tr.click()
        print("---------")
        print(driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblmobile").text)
        print("---=====---")
        driver.back()
        driver.back()
```

Just want to work this code in every time of for loop work
its work when just first time for loop works in a second time its given error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click navigates to another page, which means the driver losses the previously located elements. You need to relocate them every iteration. You can use index to keep trace on your location in the list

```
def function(foo):
    driver.get("https://truckbhada.com/PostedLoadDetails?st=Maharashtra")
    token = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="k-selectable"]/tbody/tr/td/a')

    for i in range(len(token)):
        tr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="k-selectable"]/tbody/tr/td/a')
        tr[i].click()
        tr = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnloaddetails")
        tr.click()
        print("---------")
        print(driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblmobile").text)
        print("---=====---")
        driver.back()
        driver.back()
```